# Direct link to pay to PayPal email

Tags: html, url, paypal

I'm looking for a direct link that would send funds to a PayPal user. But it would look like the Paypal checkout page.
I know this works, because I did it a while back on another project. 
Unfortunately I can not find the previous documentation that I used.
**I know this is a direct link and nothing but the email is required.**
The link looks something like this if I remember correctly.

```
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_appayment&paykey=johndoe@gmail.com
```

Here is the checkout page I'm talking about.
[PayPal checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J04f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.
This is the link.

```
paypal.com/xclick/business=johndoe@gmail.com
```

You can also edit the values like this.

```
http://paypal.com/xclick/item_name=Awesome&business=johndoe@gmail.com&amount=9.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they have turned this into its own stand alone feature.

You can visit https://www.paypal.com > sign up > create you link i.e. paypal.me/mylink

Comment: To send money to a paypal.me link, you must have an account.
While the links I posted does not.